# What use does Windows key + Tab have on a pc?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I like researching new hotkeys, and I just saw the Windows Key + Tab hotkey. 
To me it seems like it is just a fancy looking alt-tab, that is less user friendly?

Am I missing something here, or is there something else this hotkey can do?

(Running Windows 7 Enterprise)

Comment: It being more or less user friendly is a personal opinion.  It lets you switch applications.  That is its purpose.

Comment: For sure, I was just wondering if it had any extra features, since it seems to be redundant because of the existence of Alt-Tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> was introduced in Vista. It's mostly just eye-candy, but [order of windows may be different](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/07/01/8673981.aspx) than with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> if you have many windows open.

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> was then removed in Windows 8, and in Windows 10 completely different feature is bound to this shortcut. Pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows 10 shows all windows on every screen in a grid, letting you pick one with mouse. No need to hold <kbd>Win</kbd> while doing that.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the info on the new versions of Windows, I'll have to check them out on my home computer that is running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

That is pretty much it to be honest, there are ways within windows for you to be able to change what the hot keys do. But the default is what you are experiencing.

Some people find they prefer the windows key + tab (I do prefer it to alt+tab)